# viewcriteria is not working for data having word "and"

Tags: oracle-adf

i am working with applying view criteria programaticlly, till now it was fine, but when i searched with "develop and unit test" it is showing 0 records even though my table having data. iam using like operator. could any one help on this . 
i have one table, having option to filter by providing select combo box list of vales, for every column when i select any thing in lov in value change listener i am applying viewcriteria programatically on table vo.

note. every thing is programatic view object only there is no point of entity, or sql

Sample Code:

```
    DCIteratorBinding bindIterator = ADFUtils.findIterator("Tri2EWS_ETKAPIData_VO1Iterator");//Table viewObject(programatic)
    Tri2EWS_ETKAPIData_VOImpl voimpl = (Tri2EWS_ETKAPIData_VOImpl) bindIterator.getViewObject();
                ViewCriteria viewCriteria = voimpl.createViewCriteria();
                viewCriteria.setName("MyVc");
                ViewCriteriaRow viewCriteriaRow = viewCriteria.createViewCriteriaRow();
                viewCriteriaRow.setOperator("ViewAttr1", "LIKE");
                viewCriteriaRow.setAttribute("ViewAttr1", "stack and OverFlow");
                viewCriteria.add(viewCriteriaRow);
                viewCriteria.setCriteriaMode(ViewCriteria.CRITERIA_MODE_CACHE);
                voimpl.applyViewCriteria(viewCriteria, true);
                voimpl.executeQuery();
                voipmpl.getRowCount();//Getting 0 here (Actually i should get 1)
```

Comment: Please bring some code showing your problem

Comment: could you please find the sample code added.

Comment: Try to get the RowCount before using the view criteria. It should bring the original number of rows of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on debug messages for ADF BC (jbo.debugoutput) so you can see the SQL that is being generated.
This will help you figure out if the query is correctly formatted.